# Json Element returns null in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I call only `wpCategories = JsonToElement.getllAllCategory();` in the buttons `onClick` methood it works fine. (`wpCategories` get filled with data). But when I put this in a `asynctask`,  `wpCategories` returns null. (is the `doInBackground` not being called?)

Here is my buttons on click methood:

```
public void onImageGridClick(View view) {       
    new GetJsonElementTask().execute();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryGridActivity.class);       
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Extra.IMAGES, wpCategories);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the asyncTask:

```
private class GetJsonElementTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...");          
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        wpCategories = JsonToElement.getllAllCategory();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.v("DEBUG_LOG", "In onProgressUpdate");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `doInBackground()` is returning `null`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
public void onImageGridClick(View view) {       
    new GetJsonElementTask().execute();
}

    public void startCategoryGridActivity(){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryGridActivity.class);        
       intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Extra.IMAGES, wpCategories);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And the asyncTask:

```
private class GetJsonElementTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...");          
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        wpCategories = JsonToElement.getllAllCategory();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
            startCategoryGridActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.v("DEBUG_LOG", "In onProgressUpdate");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you help me one more thing: After showing Progress Dialog, it get back to previous screen (HomeActivity), and take some time to switch activity. Is any way to solve this?

Comment: @ratulalahy please explain, i didn't understand your problem. What is neme of your current activity?

Comment: current activity is: 'HomeActivity' and destination is `CategoryGridActivity`. Problem is, it is taking some time, while switching activity.

Comment: @ratulalahy it will show Progress Dialog until your AsyncTask's doInBackground method is executed and after that onPostExecute method will call. during this processing you are showing Progress Dialog with "Loading..." which make sense.

Comment: problem is, after the progress dialog dismissed, it takes some time to switch activity. For some reason this time duration is larger then normal activity switching.

Answer (score 2):

Start your Activity inside `onPostExecute` because this method execute after `doInBackground` execution complete :

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        wpCategories = JsonToElement.getllAllCategory();

        return wpCategories;  //<<< return value from here
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryGridActivity.class);       
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Extra.IMAGES, value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```